# Image without caption

Tags: html

I read that in XHTML, one has to put alt-attributes to images to get a valid img-tags. But then I saw a small rectangular area as I moved my mouse over the image. Can I make an image tag which passes validation but it won't show that rectangle as I move mouse over the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a blank `alt` (IE) and do not specify the `title` attribute (other browsers):

```
<img src="myimage.png" alt="" />
```

The spec says you need to include the `alt` attribute; however it may be blank as long as you put it there.

Comment: Doesn't just setting the attribute `title=""` do the job  cross-browser and without destroying the accessibility information of the alt attribute?